# Can MaskGroup be used with nodes other than Poster?

Tags: roku

So I was trying to have an overhang that faded out at the bottom by using a bitmap image. It doesn't seem to do anything though? I know I could just use a background image, but I'm trying to learn how to use the MaskGroup.

here's what my code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<component name="AppScene" extends="Scene" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://devtools.web.roku.com/schema/RokuSceneGraph.xsd">
  <interface>
  </interface>
    <script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/AppScene.brs"/>
  <children>
    <MaskGroup id="mask" maskUri="pkg:/images/fullsizeFade.bmp">
      <Overhang id="overhang" title="helloWorld" color="#70C835FF" />
    </MaskGroup>
    <PanelSet id="panelSet" >
      <MainListPanel id="list"/>
    </PanelSet>
  </children>
</component>
```

fullsizeFade.bmp is a 1080x115 bitmap image since that's the size that the overhang is in full def.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no problem in your code. It should work. But I still have some suggestions--

1. Check whether your device supports '**OpenGL**', because '**MaskGroup**' works with '**OpenGL**' only. You can use *'GetGraphicsPlatform()'* function of *'roDeviceInfo'* to verify this.
2. Verify that '**fullsizeFade.bmp**' is not a 9-patch image as documentation says that **MaskGroup** does not work with 9-patch images.
3. Check with adding a **'backgroundUri'** to **'Overhang'** node instead of **'color'**. It may be the case that **'MaskGroup'** works with images only.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you! These are great suggestions, I'm going to try a few and get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

I am accepting swaran's answer, but in trying out their suggestions, I made some weird discoveries which I think belong as their own answer.

1. `fullsizeFade.bmp` although it was not a 9-patch image (I believe the extension for those is `.9.bmp`) had no transparency, it was a fade from white to black. Looking at the example MaskGroup from the Roku docs, they used a png with transparency. Replacing my image with one with transparency worked.
2. When I used the transparent image, the overhang faded from the color given (green) to black, not transparent. When changing the overhang to use a `backgroundUri` instead of `color`, as swaran suggested, the overhang faded to transparent, not black. (the background uri in question was simply a green rectangle the same size as the overhang). I tried this out with several other posters and nodes (rectangles) and **`MaskGroup` seems to fade to black given a node, but to transparent given a poster**.

Given that I wanted to fade to transparent, and that `MaskGroup` only works with `OpenGL` as swaran pointed out, it would make better sense to just use a background image with transparency. I believe this will always be the better solution unless a fade to black is desired.

Comment: Thanks MMAdams, your answer is complement to my answer and giving more insight for using MaskGroup.